# Images not showing up while attempting to convert PFFile to UIImage and segue it

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimage

My code isnt functioning correctly when I click a cell and want it to segue and show the same information on a new screen.

The Text is working perfectly and showing up in the new view but the images just wont appear. I am attempting to convert a `PFFile` from Parse into a `UIImage` and use it in a array so that when I click into the cell and it displays the view it will load the correct images and data. I am on `Xcode 7 Beta 5`. It is giving me no error but still isnt displaying the data correctly.

Here is the necessary Code, if any more is required to solve the issue I will be glad to provide it.

(Whats in the first class)

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class mainScreen: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
var imageArray = [PFFile]()
var theDownloadedImages = [UIImage()]
var nameArray = [String]()
var priceArray = [String]()
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)    

{
    if segue.identifier == "cellInfo"
        {
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
        let CI = segue.destinationViewController as! cellInfo

        let imageForCell = self.imageArray[indexPath.row] as PFFile

        imageForCell.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
              if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                   self.theDownloadedImages.append(downloadedImage)

                    CI.image = self.theDownloadedImages[indexPath.row]
                    CI.name = self.nameArray[indexPath.row]
                    CI.price = self.priceArray[indexPath.row] 
              }
        }
}
}
```

(For the second Class)

```
class cellInfo: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var CILocation: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var CIImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var CIPrice: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var CIName: UILabel!

var image = UIImage()
var name = String()
var price = String()
var location = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.CIImage.image = self.image
    self.CIName.text = self.name
    self.CIPrice.text = self.price
    self.CILocation.text = self.location
}
```

Comment: Don't pass image itself just pass image name from one view to another view.

Comment: I have not actually done any work with swift yet so I can't give you exact code, but when I'm trying to do something similar to what you are doing I just pass the entire PFObject to the next ViewController. Then set everything up in viewDidLoad

Comment: Thanks Shayno it worked. I appreciate your help.